# How to correctly create a pointer to a 2D array

Tags: c++, cuda

I have created a 2D array that is meant to be [256][16] and want to create a pointer to pass it to CUDA kernel:

```
int result[matrix_rows * matrix_cols][16];
 int (*h_result)[16] = result; //host pointer
 int(*d_result)[16]; //device pointer
 
//memory allocation 
CHECK_CUDA_ERROR(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_result, matrix_rows * matrix_cols * sizeof(int)));
    
kernel << <grid, block >> > (d_flat_array, d_result);
```

But when I copy the values in the kernel to d_result, it only fills 13 out of 256 supposed elements, the indexing is correct.

I tried debugging but didn't find issues with indexes, but all arrays after [13] were null. Could the issue be in alloccation of the array and a pointer to it?

Comment: Your `d_result` is a pointer to an array of 16 `int`s.  When you say you want to allocate memory for 256 elements, does that mean 256 arrays of 16 int?  Or does it mean 256 `int`s, split among 16 arrays?

Comment: Technically, casting `&d_result` to type `void **` to match the type of the corresponding function parameter is incorrect.  The function will access the pointed-to object as if it were a `void *`, when in fact it is an `int(*)[16]`.  These probably have the same representation in your C implementation, but it is nevertheless a violation of the strict-aliasing rule.

Comment: There are 2 ways to do this as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76236630/12002570).

Comment: If the 256 elements you are talking about are arrays of 16 `int`s, you aren't allocating enough memory. The factor 16 is missing from the `cudaMalloc` call. Without the kernel signature and indexing it is very hard to decipher the intent of the code.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes, I want to allocate memory for 256 arrays of 16 int, so 4096 elements in total. I need this structure for my code but not sure how to pass the pointer to it.

Comment: @paleonix Yes, I want to allocate memory for 256 arrays of 16 int, so 4096 elements in total. I need this structure for my code but not sure how to pass the pointer to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You having clarified that you want to allocate space for 16 (rows) * 16 (columns) *arrays* of 16 `int` -- 4096 `int`s altogether -- it should be clear that this ...

> ```
> CHECK_CUDA_ERROR(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_result, matrix_rows * matrix_cols * sizeof(int)));
> ```

... does not allocate nearly enough space.  It is allocating space for just 16 * 16 = 256 `int`s.  When you try to access that space as if it were actually the intended size, undefined behavior results.  You appear to want this CUDA variation on the best-practice idiom for `malloc()`:

```
int (*d_result)[16]; //device pointer
void *allocation;
CHECK_CUDA_ERROR(cudaMalloc(&allocation, matrix_rows * matrix_cols * sizeof(*d_result)));
d_result = (int (*)[16]) allocation;
```

Note well that

1. The amount of space is defined in terms of the total number of elements wanted (`matrix_rows * matrix_cols`) and the size of each element (`sizeof(*d_result)`).
2. The allocation result pointer is stored in a variable of type `void *` (`allocation`), the address of which does not need to be cast.  This conforms to the strict aliasing rule, whereas your approach does not.  That result is then converted to the desired type (which would be automatic in C, but is not in C++) and assigned to the intended variable.

Comment: I cannot do this (d_result = (void*)allocation;) because I have an error: "a value type void* cannot be assigned to value type int(*)[16]"

Comment: My mistake, @imNotARobot, I wrote the wrong cast.  I just corrected it.  If you prefer, you may also use an equivalent `static_cast` in place of the C-style cast.

Answer (score 0):

> How to correctly create a pointer to a 2D array

There are 2 ways to do this as shown below:

##### Method 1

Use `decltype` with modern c++:

```
//                      v---------->note the & operator
decltype(&result) ptr = &result;
```

---

##### Method 2

Use `auto` placeholder type:

```
auto* ptr = &result;
```

---

##### Method 3

The correct syntax would be as shown below. Also note the `&` at the right hand side that is used to take the address of the 2D array:

```
int (*ptr)[matrix_rows * matrix_cols][16] = &result;
```

---

As you can see, method 1 and method 2 are more readable than method 3.

Comment: Using these methods I get a "Cast to type "value_type" is not allowed" error